# make a left block to show categories on a page?

Tags: magento2

How can I create a left block and assign it to categories left panel in magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

First create `catalog_category_view.xml`

> app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout

***Then add code in this file for add a block***.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::left/test.phtml" name="block_name" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The create template files `test.phtml`at

> app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/left/

**add code:**

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Test') 
echo $block->getNameLayout();
```

Comment: I want to show this on  page where product of categories appear

Comment: is it possible ?